# Retrofit правильно как авторизоваться в header?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

есть сайт data.gov.spb.ru/developers
нужно получить список данных оттуда 
как с помощью retrofit организовать правильную авторизацию?
на сайте сказано вот это:
Токен передаётся в HTTP Header в формате “Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b” 
То, что получилось у меня:

```
@GET("/api/v1/datasets")
    @Headers("Authorization: Token e0fdb92b7fcbbf9241a9a8f22b592b3d83544ffa")
    Call<List<PostModel>> getData(@Query("id")int count, @Query("name") String resourceName);
```

при запуске приложение вылетает

MainActivity

```
package com.example.mikhailzagrebaev.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<PostModel> posts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        posts = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.posts_recycle_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        PostsAdapter adapter = new PostsAdapter(posts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        App.getApi().getData( 5,"name").enqueue(new Callback<List<PostModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<PostModel>> call, Response<List<PostModel>> response) {
                posts.addAll(response.body());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<PostModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

log

```
        03-18 22:41:50.248 19559-19559/com.example.mikhailzagrebaev.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: 
    main Process: com.example.mikhailzagrebaev.myapplication, 
    PID: 19559 java.lang.NullPointerException:
     Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()'
 on a null object reference at java.io.StringReader.(StringReader.java:50) 
    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert(Html.java:765)
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:245) 
    at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:199)
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете что ошибка в этом? Может быть ещё миллион причин почему приложение вылетает. Прикладывайте стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: 03-18 22:41:50.248 19559-19559/com.example.mikhailzagrebaev.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.example.mikhailzagrebaev.myapplication, PID: 19559
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
at java.io.StringReader.(StringReader.java:50)
at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert(Html.java:765)
at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:245)
at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:199)
итд

Comment: Аналогичная проблема!удалось как-то решить?